# Caching output of last few shell-run command sans 'script'?

Tags: caching, shell

Can I cache the output of the last few commands I ran from tcsh? Notes:

- I often run a slow and verbose command from tcsh, forget to 
  redirect/tee the output, and have the results scroll off the 
  screen. Solutions I've considered:

  - Run everything inside 'script'. This seems like overkill, since 
    it saves the output of everything, not just the last few 
    commands. I suppose you could cleverly rotate script output files 
    somehow, but this seems ugly.
  - Screen/rxvt/xterm scrollback. This actually works fairly well, 
    unless the output is voluminous (which it often is).
  - Run the command again. Obviously, this is what I'm hoping to 
    avoid (though, thanks to filesystem caching, the rerun is often 
    quicker than the first run).
  - Try to stop being so damn stupid. No hope whatsoever.

EDIT: One thought: can I make tcsh run a "post command" on everything 
I type in? For example, if I say "ls", it secretly runs "ls | tee 
/tmp/lastout.txt" or something? Is there some setenv variable that 
does this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to increase the size of the scrollback buffer in `screen` (the default is 100 lines).

```
screen -h 1000
```

or in `~/.screenrc`:

```
defscrollback 1000
```

Comment: Actually, I'd already done this (but forgot to mention it). The output that scrolls off is often 10K+ lines. I once tried "scrollback 1000000" (in ~/.screenrc) but screen's memory usage grew too large.

Comment: @barry: Sorry to say this, but if you're talking about 10,000 lines then I think you should concentrate on the last bullet point in your question. I don't mean to be harsh, but it's something I work on for myself. Redirection and `tee` are your friends as is filtering your output so that you only have to look at summaries or exceptions.

Comment: To be fair, I often do tee output results, especially when I know there will be 10K+ lines. The general worst case is when I expect only a few lines of output but end up w/ 10K+.